# How to determine existence of greatest and least element on order relation over non numbers?

Tags: proof-verification, relations, order-theory

> Given a number $n>1, n\in \mathbb N$, let $P$ be a totally ordered relation over set $A=\{1,2,..,n\}$. That is $(a,b)\in P \iff a\le b$.
>
> In addition let $t\notin A$ and let relation $Q=\{(1,t),(t,t)\}$
>
> Does $P\cup Q$ have a greatest and least element?

What troubles me is that we don't know what $t$ is, so maybe it's not even a number. In that case how can we determine what the least number is, by simply checking which element is in relation with **all** other elements? In our case it would be $1$ I guess.

But then if we don't know what is the exact relation between elements in $P\cup Q$ then we might have as well picked $1$ as the greatest element.

However if we suppose that $1$ indeed is the least element in $P\cup Q$ then in order to determine the greatest element I guess there're multiple cases:

1. if $t\in \mathbb N$ then $t$ is the greatest element.
2. if $t < 0$ then $t$ is the least element while $n$ becomes the greatest element.
3. if $0\le t < 1$ - same as case 2.
4. if $t$ is not a number then we don't have a greatest element because $t$ is not in relation with $A- \{1\}$

I'm not sure if I'm overcomplicating the problem with cases or whether I should only concentrate on case 4.

Comment: What does the matrix $Q$ mean?  That doesn't look like a relation, or even a set, to me.

Comment: @saulspatz it is a relation with two ordered pairs: $(1,m), (m,m)$

Comment: Then you should write it as a set: $\{(1,m),(m,m)\}$

Comment: You also have a deep seated mistake in the very first line. You take $P$ to be *a totally ordered relation over $A$*. But then you claim that $P$ is really just the restriction of the usual $\leq$. This is patently false. The relation defined by $2\prec 1$ on $\{1,2\}$ is a total order of that set, but it is exactly the opposite of $\leq$. The point of taking *a* [something] is that you impose exactly zero restrictions over it, other than the properties of being [something].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your statement that "we don't know what is the exact relation between elements in P∪Q" is mistaken.  We are told exactly what the relation is.  You are correct that $1$ is the least element.  $(1,a)\in P\cup Q$ because if $a\in A$ then $(1,a)\in P$ and if $a=t,$ then $(1,a)\in Q.$

There is no greatest element.  The greatest element in $A$ is $n$, but $(t,n)\notin P\cup Q$

All that we are concerned with is $A\cup {t}.$  As William Elliot said in his answer, your remarks about numbers outside this set are off-base.  In particular, it doesn't matter if $t$ is not a number.  In fact, it's common to write $\infty$ to designate an element outside some set.  We don't care what it is; we just know it's not in the set.

Answer (score 1):

t is not in A.
I presume Q is the order 1 < t, t <= t.
R = P $\cup$ Q is a partial order for B = A $\cup$ {t}.

Anything outside of B is of no concern, a distraction.
Your 1,2,3 are nonsense as they are about stuff not in B.
4 is more or less floundering, but in the ball park.

Show B has a minimum element.  What is it?
Show B has no maximum element but two maximal elements.
What are they?

Comment: The least number for B is $1$ because $1$ is in relation with all other elements in B. The two maximum elements in B are $n$ and $m$ because there's no element $x \in A, x \neq n$ such that $n\le x$ because it's given that $A$ is totally ordered set and $n$ is the greatest number in it. Also $m$ is in relation with $1$ but not in relation with any other element of $A$ so it's a maximal element of $B$ as well.

Comment: There can be at most one maximum. element!  Who is this nobody m?  'In  relation' is ambigious.

Comment: sorry I meant $t$ instead of $m$. I think we're using different terminologies: in my terminology there can be multiple maximal, minimal elements and only one greatest/least element as described in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximal_and_minimal_elements. I used "in relation" because $\forall x\in A: 1 \le x$ so $P$ is a "$\le$" relation. However we don't know how the relation is defined for $Q$ (why did you assume that the order is $1<t, t<=t$ for $Q$? this information is not given) so the only available connection between $1$ and $t$ is simply being "in binary relation".

Comment: @user123429842  Q was defined as a matrix and then edited to the same as a set.  There is a big difference between the maximum element and a maximal element.